# Multiple AWS stacks sharing a common CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a webapp set up with its content on S3, and a CloudFront distribution serving that content from a custom domain name. It's deployed as a CloudFormation stack which "owns" the distribution, the s3 bucket etc.

Now I need to have multiple webapps sharing that same distribution, each under its own subpath, so that my-app.com/path1 opens the first webapp, and my-app.com/path2 opens the second webapp, etc. The apps are in separate gits and separate CF stacks (which up until now also contain their own respective CloudFront distributions).

How can this be set up in a manageable way? Unfortunately, it seems a CF distribution is an "atomic" resource in CloudFormation - it has to be created with its full set of origins and behaviours inline - it's not possible to "decentralize" it by creating the distribution in one stack, and then have other stacks add origins and behaviours to the existing distribution resource (it seems many AWS resources worked this way from the start, but over time support was added for partial decentralization, such as for API gateway resources where API keys, methods etc may be added as separate resources referencing the "parent" resource instead of having to be an inline *part of* the parent resource, but it doesn't seem like this has happened for CloudFront resources).

Even with the AWS SDK/CLI, it's only possible to completely replace a distribution's configuration by supplying a complete array of origins, behaviours etc - it's not possible to add/remove origins individually. So a script that adds app X's origin into the shared distribution would have to be a get-modify-put kind of operation, which seems very messy/dangerous.

This means that the code will be messy, with ugly dependencies from the stack containing the distribution, it having to know all the details of several different apps (cache policies for /path1, /path2 and so on), instead of having each app own its part of the distribution config.
The best approach I can think of is to have the app stacks own their own buckets and other non-cloudfront resources and export their S3 URLs etc, and then have the distribution stack import those parameters from each of the app stacks, and set up the static list of origins, paths, behaviours etc.

Is there a way to avoid this that I've missed, so that each app can define - and deploy - only its own "part" of the common distribution?